# how to simplify the so many question mark in the insert string ？

Tags: python

The table in one database has 30 fields ,when i write some  data into table ,how to handle the `?` in insert string?

```
many="? ,"*30
many=many[0:-1]
db_str='INSERT INTO the_table  VALUES (' + many + ');'
con.executemany(db_str, data)
```

The db_str is ugly for people to use ,how can i make the code look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a slightly cleaner way might be to use `join`:

```
parameters = ", ".join(["?"] * 30)
query = 'INSERT INTO the_table VALUES(%s);' % parameters
con.executemany(query, data)
```

Comment: it is insecure!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22586133/why-the-sql-command-is-insecure

Comment: @it_is_a_literature no, it's not insecure. You just completely failed to understand both this answer and the answer you linked. While using `%s` to directly insert user-entered data into a query is of course insecure and leaves you open for SQL injections, here `%s` is only used to insert the parameter placeholders into the query. This is basically a cleaner alternative to using `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature another way of explaining it is, using %s is insecure when you don't know what you're substituting in. In this case, we defined what we're substituting in (lots of question marks in a string). the `data` is still being prepared properly.